# Как добиться того чтобы browsersync автообновлял страницу?

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp-watch

Всем привет. Пытаюсь разобраться в gulp установил browserSync и gulp-watch. Пытаюсь добиться автообновления страницы браузера реагирующего на изменение html и css.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch(['app/*.html', 'app/css/**/*.css'],  gulp.parallel( browserSync.reload )));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Надо было писать

```js
gulp.watch(['./app/*.html','./app/css/**/*.css']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
```